# Smooth play of live network audio samples

Tags: winapi, signal-processing, audio-streaming

I am writing a client/server app in that server send live audio data that capture audio samples that captured from some external device( mic. for example ) and send it to the client. Then client want to play those samples. My app will run on local network so I have no problem with bandwidth( My sound is 8k, 8bit stereo while my net card 1000Mb ). In client I buffer the data for a small time and then start playback. and as data arrive from server I send them to sound card. This seems to work fine but there is a problem:
when my buffer in the client side finished, I will experience gaps in played sound.
I consider this is because of the difference in sampling time of the server and the client, it means that 8K on server is not same as 8K on client.
I can solve this with pausing client's playback and buffer again, but my boss doesn't accept it, since I have proper bandwidth and I should be able to play sound with no gap or pause.
So I decided to dynamically change playback speed in the client but I don't know how.

I am programming in Windows( native ) and I currently use waveOutXXX to play the sound. I can use any other native library( DirectX/DirectSound, Jack or ... ) but they should provide a smooth playback in the client.

I have programmed with waveOutXXX many times without any problem and I know it good but I can't solve my problem of dynamic resampling

Comment: Btw, there may also be effects of network data buffering such that the network stack tries to pre-buffer data (in order to send it in larger chunks more effectively) at first resulting in rare sending of small pieces of data and gaps on the receiving side.

Comment: This is a very good note but since I have a continous data( 16K each second ) is it really effect of buffering of the network? and also I buffer data for 1 second so specified problem should not be something that can create gap in my playback system

Comment: I think the best thing is to make a test to see what's happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that your problem isn't likely due to mis-matched sample rates, but something to do with your buffering.  You should be continuously dumping data to the sound card, and continuously filling your buffer.  Use a reasonable buffer size... 300ms should be enough for most applications.

Now, over long periods of time, it is possible for the clock on the recording side and the clock on the playback side to drift apart enough that the 300ms buffer is no longer sufficient.  I would suggest that rather than resampling at such a small difference, which could introduce artifacts, simply add samples at the encoding end.  You still record at 8kHz, but you might add a sample or two every second, to make that 8.001kHz or so.  Simply doubling one of the existing samples for this (or even a simple average between one sample and the next) will not be audible.  Adjust this as necessary for your application.

Comment: Thanks Brad for your response. but I use a 1 second buffer not 300 ms and I still have problem. And I say that I have played many wave files without any problem, so I know that where I should add buffers to be played, but the idea to add one or more samples in the playing side look braliant. what can I do if playing side is faster than recording side?! and why I have the error with so large buffer( 1s )

Comment: @BigBoss, I think the problem is not with buffering specifically, but with an error in your code or methodology. You need to produce a steady stream of data to be sent to the sound card, just as if you were playing one long WAV file. You cannot send one buffer, then another buffer, and then another. You need to programmtically concatenate these buffers and steadily send them to the sound card's buffer. Adding samples fixes the problem of the playback side being faster than the recording side. If you add too many samples, you can do the opposite. Telemetry on the remote buffer would be useful.

Comment: let me explain my program. I receive data from my server. I will break it into fixed chunks of voice and buffer them for up to 1 second then start my playback, write all prepared wave headers to the sound card and then upon receiving of data from the server when size of that data be as much as my fixed length I add a new buffer to the sound card( if I have a returned wave header ) or I buffer data for next time that windows inform me of WOM_DONE.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem in an application I worked on.  It did not involve network, but it did involve source data being captured in real-time at a certain fixed sampling rate, a large amount of signal processing, and finally output to the sound card at a fixed rate.  Like you, I had gaps in the playback at buffer boundaries.

It seemed to me like the problem was that the processing being done caused audio data to make it to the sound card in a very jerky manner.  That is, it would get a large chunk, then it would be a long time before it got another chunk.  The overall throughput was correct, but this latency caused the sound card to often be starved for data.  I suppose you may have the same situation with the network piece in your system.

The way I solved it was to first make the audio buffer longer.  Then, every time a new chunk of audio was received, I checked how full the buffer was.  If it was less than 20% full, I would write some silence to make it around 60% full.

You may think that this goes against reducing the gaps in playback since it is actually adding a gap, but it actually helps.  The problem that I was having was that even though I had a significantly large audio buffer, I was always right at the verge of it being empty.  With the other latencies in the system, this resulted in playback gaps on almost every buffer.

Writing the silence when the buffer started to get empty, but before it actually did, ensured that the buffer always had some data to spare if the processing fell behind a little.  Also, just a single small gap in playback is very hard to notice compared to many periodic gaps.

I don't know if this will work for you, but it should be easy to implement and try out.

Comment: As you say it is easy to implement and test, I will check it tommorrow and let you know the result